# Como iniciar un proyecto en react native?

Tags: react-native

Al ejecutar `npx react-native run-android`, ocurre lo siguiente

> info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
> Jetifier found 960 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
> info JS server already running.
> info Launching emulator...
> error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
> warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
> info Installing the app...
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
> Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
> See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
> - Try:
>   Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   BUILD FAILED in 5s
>   error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up:
>   https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>   Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

El error es algo largo, alguien sabe que hacer? soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: debes de tener instalado algún emulador android, para esto te recomiendo descargarte android studio y crear un dispositivo virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente debes usar AndroidX, para migrar automáticamente tu proyecto incluyendo las bibliotecas de terceros existentes para usar las dependencias de AndroidX debes agregar dentro de tu archivo `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

ahora realiza lo siguiente :

```
   $ npm install --save-dev jetifier   
   $ npx jetify
```

e inicia como lo que indica el mensaje, agrega el flag:

```
   $ npx react-native run-android --no-jetifier
```

Revisa:

[Cómo migrar a AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)